# Could not render URDF file due to an error

Tags: urdf, xacro

Could not render URDF due to the following error:

```
Error: Vector ${vec} does not have 3 values Error: Vector ${vec} does not have 3 values at h
 (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:1383161) at 
 https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:1389533 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at 
 https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:1386698 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at y 
 (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:1386443) at S 
 (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:1388481) at 
 https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/tejasbh/.vscode/extensions/ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5/dist/webview.js:2:13902...
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I am afraid to say that this question may be voted for closing as it does not provide any information. For example, which command packages did you execute? How and where did you notice the error? Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.